# Custom moving sum

Tags: kdb

I would like to create a five entry moving sum from a trade table. I;e; each row should be the sum of the size of the previous trades. The snag is that Id like from those 5 rows only to drop the highest and lowest priced row.

Is this possible?

RD

Comment: What behaviour do you expect when there are less than 5 values in the bucket? Still remove highest and lowest?

Comment: For the first 2 records you can assume no value exists. [ null?]
For the 3rd it would use the "middle" only. After the first record its no problem.

Comment: q)t:([]p: 1 2 3 2 3 4 5;s: 2 3 4 5 4 3 2)
q)
q)t
p s
---
1 2
2 3
3 4
2 5
3 4
4 3
5 2

For the firth row the sizes are 2 3 4 5 4
The min price is 1 ( row zero) and the max price is 3 ( row 2) 
Thus the sum is 3+5+5
[ In cases where 2 mins or maxes exist  drop the first row ]

Comment: Hmmm, I don't get where your 3+5+5 comes from. Your sizes are `2 3 4 5 4` corresponding to prices `1 2 3 2 3`. If you're excluding `price=1` and the first of the `price=3` then you'd be left with sizes `3 5 4`. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I think this function will work

```
q)trade:([]price:100?100f;size:100?100)
q)w:{(til[count z]-m)+x each flip reverse prev\[m:y-1;z]}
q)update top:size w[{x?max x};5;price],bot:size w[{x?min x};3;price],ms:5 msum size,rms:(5 msum size)-((size w[{x?max x};5;price])+(size w[{x?min x};5;price])) from trade 
price     size top bot ms  rms
------------------------------
64.14975  70   70  70  70  -70
90.82711  36   36  70  106 0
97.96094  12   12  70  118 36
30.77491  97   12  97  215 106
36.52273  92   12  97  307 198
95.91177  99   12  97  336 227
41.21866  45   12  92  345 236
63.3041   83   99  45  416 220
57.52693  94   99  45  413 222
0.9011743 8    99  8   329 222
14.48057  97   83  8   327 236
77.06132  52   52  8   334 274
36.96114  66   52  97  317 257
11.75355  24   52  24  247 187
92.34386  60   60  24  299 215
40.15936  69   60  24  271 187
56.19037  8    60  69  227 143
72.4948   62   60  69  223 139
81.12026  95   60  8   294 165
20.86614  59   95  59  293 139
```

The function `w` will allow selection and removal of the sizes corresponding to the max and min prices. This is done in the update by (msum size)-(top+bot). Unfortunately there is an issue with the first element, I will comment with a solution to this if I find one.

Comment: Yes - the other solutions are not accounting for the fact that it's the sum of sizes based on removal of max/min *prices* rather than the sum of sizes based on the removal of max/min *size*. Makes the problem a lot trickier. What makes it even trickier again is that it likely has to be done `by sym`

Comment: Agreed, though you'd still have a negative on the first row of each sym. This could be fixed with a floor of zero, using `update rms:0|(5 msum size)-((size w[{x?max x};5;price])+(size w[{x?min x};5;price])) from trade`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you should be able to do this with a sliding window with a custom function:

```
q)func:{sum[x] - min[x] + max[x]}
q)swin:{[f;w;s] f each { 1_x,y }\[w#0;s]}
q)swin[func; 5; til 1000]
```

for example.

Comment: I believe OP is looking for a solution in kdb+/q (note kdb tag), this appears to be python?

Comment: Didn't notice the tag.  My mistake.  Thought I had used a different filter.

Comment: @JonathonMcMurray Updated answer to use kdb.

Comment: nice :) I think your answer falls foul to right-to-left evaluation in kdb though, all the values in x will have max x subtracted from them, then the minimum of these values will be substracted from each value in x before summing. rewriting func as `func:{sum[x]-min[x]-max[x]}` should work. Another option would be `func:{sum 1_-1_asc x}` to drop highest & lowest.

Comment: No, it would have to be `{sum[x]-min[x]+max[x]}` but this doesn't cover the (possible) edge case of when there are less than 5 values.

Comment: @terrylynch yep, came back to comment that when I thought it through a little more!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (by sym):

```
q)t:([]sym:20?`a`b`c;px:20?1.0;sz:20?1000)
q)update msz:{sum((),x`sz)@-1_1_iasc(),x`px}each{-5 sublist'x,'y}\[([]px;sz)] by sym from t
sym px         sz  msz
-----------------------
c   0.4707883  908 0
a   0.6346716  360 0
b   0.9672398  522 0
a   0.2306385  257 0
a   0.949975   858 360
a   0.439081   585 945
c   0.5759051  90  0
c   0.5919004  683 90
c   0.8481567  90  773
b   0.389056   869 0
b   0.391543   468 468
a   0.08123546 959 1202
b   0.9367503  221 689
c   0.2782122  694 1681
c   0.2392341  934 1467
a   0.1508133  865 1707
a   0.1567317  344 1794
b   0.9785     997 1211
a   0.7043314  314 1794
b   0.9441671  580 1269
```